# Multidimensional tensorgrid using mgrid in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I want to generate a multidimensional tensor grid of dimension D from the one-dimensional nodes stored in an array x with non-equidistant nodes, e.g.

```
x = array([1., 0.7., 0., -0.7., -1.])
```

I tried to build a list with D entries:

```
xlist = []
for i in range (D):
    xlist.append(x)
```

But this does not work as input for mgrid, which tells that object has no attribute 'step':

```
X=np.mgrid[xlist]
```

I am new to Python and used most of the time Matlab. Any advice would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Have you read the documentation (including the example) for [mgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html)? It doesn't accept a list, but slices.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From this point I would think that mgrid is not suitable to build tensorgrids for non-equidistant points in each dimension, since it requires an equidistant stepping?

Comment: Indeed, I don't think it is. I wouldn't know what is menat my a tensor grid, but perhaps there is another Python package that can do this. I don't think numpy has what you're looking for.